Numerical solve in NetLogo
We are using a mass balance model (Dynamic Energy Budget Theory based), and know that for 2 (maybe 3) parameters, we will need to use numerical solving methods to calculate fluxes (it says this in the book and other papers).
We have two problems:

we cannot fathom an approach for the code; and
setting up the underlying pseudocode (we don't often use numerical methods).

We need to simultaneously solve for a parameter (specific growth rate), r and two parameters that it depends on, J_EcC and J_EnC. This is definitely the only way to solve it, there is no analytical solution.
I have an equation for each. The equation for r contains both of the other terms, and the equations for J_EcC and J_EnC both have r in them. I will put the equations at the very end, but I don't want to bog down the question with them here.
We would like to take a bisectional solution approach, as this is what we have seen done with this model before in NetLogo for other numerical method analyses...and it probably will work.
The problem in NetLogo is that it seems if we want to do bisectional analysis, we have to directly have the combined equations in one single substitute equation, which becomes excessively long and awful. Surely there is an easier way? Also, I am just confused at the general pseudocode strategy for how to implement a bisectional analysis, and it seems there are no built in functions in NetLogo that would be of use.
Example code from a similar problem but completely different application is seen below (From Martin et al. 2013, The American Naturalist):
; calculate the initial energy of the first individuals using a bisection method

to calc-embryo-reserve-investment
  set lower-bound 0
  ifelse ticks = 0
  [set upper-bound 100000]
  [set upper-bound U_R * kap_R]
  set sim 0

  loop[
    set sim sim + 1

    set estimation .5 * (lower-bound + upper-bound)
    set L_embryo  L_0
    set U_E_embryo estimation
    set U_H_embryo  0
    set e_scaled_embryo v_rate * (U_E_embryo / L_embryo  ^ 3)

    ifelse ticks = 0[set e_ref 1][set e_ref e_scaled]  ; e_ref now determines which e_scaled_embryo to calculate: 1 for ticks = 0 (in the setup procedure), e_scaled otherwise

    while [U_H_embryo  < U_H^b and e_scaled_embryo > e_ref ]
     [ set e_scaled_embryo v_rate * (U_E_embryo / L_embryo  ^ 3)
        set S_C_embryo L_embryo  ^ 2 * (g * e_scaled_embryo / (g + e_scaled_embryo)) * (1 + (L_embryo  / (g * (v_rate / ( g * k_M_rate)))))

        set dU_E_embryo  ( -1 * S_C_embryo )
        set dU_H_embryo  ((1 - kap) * S_C_embryo - k_J_rate * U_H_embryo  )
        set dL_embryo   ((1 / 3) * (((V_rate /( g * L_embryo  ^ 2 )) * S_C_embryo) - k_M_rate * L_embryo ))

        set  U_E_embryo  U_E_embryo +  dU_E_embryo    / (timestep )
        set  U_H_embryo   U_H_embryo  +  dU_H_embryo   / (timestep )
        set  L_embryo   L_embryo  +  dL_embryo    / (timestep )
      ]

    if e_scaled_embryo <  .05 +  e_ref and e_scaled_embryo > -.05 + e_ref and U_H_embryo  >= U_H^b  [

      ifelse ticks = 0 ;
      [set U_E^0 estimation
        set L L_0
        set U_E U_E^0
        set U_H 0
        set U_R 0
        set dU_R  0

        set age-day random timestep
        stop
      ][stop]]

    ifelse U_H_embryo  > U_H^b
      [ set upper-bound estimation ]
      [ set lower-bound estimation ]
    if sim > 200 [user-message ("Embryo submodel did not converge. Timestep may need to be smaller.") stop]
    ;if the timestep is too big relative to the speed of growth of species this will no converge
  ]
end

